# Can I have one workflow in informatica handle mappings for three different types of files based on the filename

Tags: file, session, mapping, workflow, informatica

I have a directory of files where each file is in one of three file formats. We can use the filename to determine the file format for mapping data. I would like to loop through all the files in the directory and based on the filename direct it towards the associated session mapping, delete the file on success, update the control table and then move to the next file. I'd like the execution to be deterministic. What are some of my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it you dont want to have three workflows but want the same session to handle all files? It is difficult to get the workflow to run different sessions based on filenames. The easiest way is to let the mapping handle this. If you list your filenames in a textfile and instruct the session to load using indirect file and name the textfile as source the source qualifier can give you the name of the file currently being loaded. Then the mapping can treat the flow differently based on that filename. Note that all files listed in the textfile will be processed at the same time.

Comment: Thanks. Since all of the files will be processed at the same time, would  the failure and suspend of one prevent the other mappings from completing? Also, I'm not against three workflows as long as the overall process is deterministic.

Comment: No, the mapping could i.e. be designed so that the SQ reads the entire record of the source file without bothering about format, e.g. a single varchar of the maximum recordlength of your three filetypes. The second transformation in the mapping is a router that directs the record to one of three distinct groups, each moving on to transforms handling one of the three formats.

Comment: The again if you just as easily can use seperate sessions or workflows there are a number of other simpler alternatives, i.e. just have a 3 different workflows each waiting for a particular file and process it accordingly